# c++ No exception thrown while expecting out_of_range

Tags: c++

Consider the following source:

```
void ex8()
{
    vector<int> v;

    try
    {
        v.push_back(3);
        int i = v[1];
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "pas bon !";
    }
}
```

When executing, no exception is thrown in Release. In Debug, I get a Debug Assertion Failed dialog.
I'am using Visual Studio on Win 10.

Is the vector implementation not supposed to throw an out_of_range exception?

Thank you.

Comment: `Is the vector implementation not supposed to throw an out_of_range exception?` No it's not.

Comment: If you want  an exception, use `at()`, not `[]`.

Comment: I got this example from Bjarne stroupstrup's programming book! He explains that the vector::operator[] throw an exception in this case. So, is bjarne wrong? or is this linked to the windows implementation of vector?

Comment: @Tibeben Do you have a quote?

Comment: Which book (there are several)? BTW The debug will have "checked iterators" to warn you about this kind of thing, while release will just let you (try to) access things that aren't there.

Comment: @Tibeben -- *He explains that the vector::operator[] throw an exception in this case* -- Then you better get a hold of Stroustrup and have him correct this in his programming book.

Comment: @Tibeben [See the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).  Note what it says -- **No bounds checking is performed**.  In other words, `vector` is just as dangerous and unpredictable as an array if you access an element out-of-bounds.  Since `vector::operator [ ]` is an actual function and not simply a pair of brackets used to access array elements, Visual C++ has a chance to perform the check in debug mode by adding code to the `[ ]` function to check for boundary access violations.

Comment: The book : Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (§5.6.2 Range errors) [link](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Comment: Have you perhaps confused "**may** throw an `out_of_range` exception" with "**will** throw an `out_of_range` exception"?

Answer (score 0):

Just an example with `[]` and `at()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;

  v.push_back(123);
  v.resize(0);

  try {
    std::cout << "at() ";
    std::cout  << v.at(0) << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "[] " << v[0] << std::endl; // all can append

  return 0;
}
```

For me the execution is

```
at() std::exception
[] 123
```